# How should I understand "is its own"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

In general I do not understand the usage of "is its own" in a sentence. For example how should I understand "is its own" in the following sentence?

> Since the hand of a clock **is its own** clearly definable concept, it is a good idea to create it an own class – `BoundedCounter` – for the sake of human readability.

Because I do not understand "is its own" I cannot rephrase the above sentence so it is not clear to me how to intepret the meaning of the sentence

Comment: Best if you'd include how you understand it after checking a dictionary.

Comment: @shin - I'm all in favor of asking newer users to provide [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), but dictionaries aren't always the best place to go look. (I wonder how [this page](https://www.wordnik.com/words/own) would help a learner answer this question?)

Answer (score 2):

*is its own* is not a phrase.

*its own clearly definable concept* is a noun phrase, the complement of *is*.

*Its own* here means "standing on its own, not requiring reference to something else" rather than "belonging to itself".